# How can I extract forum post's author with jsoup?

Tags: java, html, tags, jsoup

```
            <div class="username_container">

                    <div id="yui-gen11" class="popupmenu memberaction">
<a id="yui-gen13" class="username offline popupctrl" href="member.php?u=276113" title="PilotPhill is offline"><strong>**PilotPhill**</strong></a>
<ul id="yui-gen12" class="popupbody memberaction_body">

    <li class="left">
```

I am trying to extract the author names of a forum thread using jsoup.  It is the name inside the strong tags.  I have tried close to everything and just can't get it.
Any tips?  I've been using jSoup.select() but if there are other methods, I'd be happy to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use `Document.select` as you already found out.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.foo.com").get();
Elements usernames = doc.select("a.username strong");
for (Element username: usernames) {
    System.out.println("found username: " + username.text();
}
```

`a.username strong` means: tags `strong` inside tag `a` with attribute `class` having the value `username` as in :

```
<a id="yui-gen13" class="username offline popupctrl" 
    href="member.php?u=276113" title="PilotPhill is offline">
    <strong>**PilotPhill**</strong>
</a>
```